# Show button with delay Android Java

Tags: android, animation

I want create some simple animation for my program. 
There is 4 invisible button, and that I want is when program is started, 
those button will visible with delay.

Show button 1 -> button 2 -> and so on.

I tried this, but when program running, all button will appear in same time.

```
try {
((Button) findViewById(R.id.f1)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Thread.sleep(1200);
((Button) findViewById(R.id.f2)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Thread.sleep(1200);
((Button) findViewById(R.id.f3)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Thread.sleep(1200);
((Button) findViewById(R.id.f4)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Thread.sleep(1200);
 } catch (Exception e) {
 }
```

anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a Handler:

```
private Handler handler;

private void showButtons(){
    handler = new Handler();

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.f1)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}, 1200);

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.f2)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}, 2400);

//etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This do not relate with this question, but if you sleep main thread(just like what you do)
It can make your application freeze